# How far can one continue to use the Polyakov formalism in string theory?

Tags: string-theory

Polyakov action is often used to introduce string theory. But many introductory texts do not make clear when one should stop using the Polyakov formalism. It seems reasonable to think that the Polyakov formalism stops working, if any lesson is to be drawn from quantum field theory, where particle worldline formalism no longer suffices. But I am not sure where I am headed toward.

Comment: Are you only talking about the bosonic string, or are you also talking about the super string?

Comment: @Qmechanic Superstring as well - though/and lack of my knowledge about superstrings is one of reasons why I ask this question anyway so that I can have some guidance before I have to study superstrings.

Comment: In QFT the worldline formalism is enough for perturbative computations, i.e. get results as a power expansion on the coupling constant. The same goes for the string theory. The worldsheet formalism do perturbative computations of string theory.